# i am using a class that act as restful webservice. When i call a method which returns html output i am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Below is my restful web-service class which contains a method that produces **HTML** output. I am using Apache Tomcat V8.0.20

```
@Path("/cardvalidate")
public class cardclass 
{

     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
     public String validate(@QueryParam("name") String name,@QueryParam("cardno") String cardno,@QueryParam("cvv") String cvv,@QueryParam("amount") String amount)
     {


        String returnparam = new String();
        Connection con = null;

        try
        {


            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/f1","ramji","mysql");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select 1 from credit_card where name = ? and cardnumber = ? and cvv = ?"); 

            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, cardno);
            ps.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(cvv));

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                    if(Integer.parseInt(amount)>100000){
                        returnparam= "<html><body><h3>Transaction amount has exceeded the limit. Transaciton cancelled</h3></body></html>";
                    } else {
                        returnparam = "<html><body><h3>Transaciton successfull</h3></body></html>";
                    }

                } else {
                    returnparam = "<html><body><h3>Invalid card details. Transaction cancelled</h3></body></html>";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        return returnparam;

    }
}
```

When I am calling this method through URL `http://localhost:8080/final_project/rest/cardvalidate?name=ramji&cardno=12345&cvv=663&amount=1000`

Where **'final_project'** is the Application Name, **'rest'** is base URL for restful service, **'cardvalidate'** is used to call the **cardclass** and its method.
I am getting following error :

```
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse
 SEVERE: Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
 at  org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:195)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapper.java:100)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:176)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder$1.getOutputStream(ServerRuntime.java:654)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.flushBuffer(CommittingOutputStream.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:261)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.close(CommittingOutputStream.java:276)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.close(OutboundMessageContext.java:839)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:412)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:737)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:421)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:411)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
at final_project.myfilter.doFilter(myfilter.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is there in your `final_project.myfilter.doFilter(myfilter.java:45)`

Comment: You should use `*` instead of `1` in your SQLQuery, or you can specified `Columns` like `SELECT  NAME, CARDNUMBER, CVV, AMOUNT FROM CREDIT_CARD`

Comment: i am using 'select 1' to check any record is there in database for the given constraints. i am not retrieving the columns. i just want to know if it exists or not. so i am using 'select 1'.

Comment: myfilter is filter class. do filter is a method which filters any unauthorized access. whenever control is redirected to a html page or servlet, it will first go to filter class, checks for session parameters, if it is unauthorized access it redirect to login page, else to the intended page or servlet.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, this should solve your Problem.

```
@Path("/cardvalidate")
public class cardclass 
{

 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
 public String validate(@QueryParam("name") String name,@QueryParam("cardno") String cardno,@QueryParam("cvv") String cvv,@QueryParam("amount") String amount)
 {


        String returnparam = new String();
        Connection con = null;

        try
        {


            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/f1","ramji","mysql");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select * from credit_card where name = ? and cardnumber = ? and cvv = ?"); 

            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, cardno);
            ps.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(cvv));

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                    if(Integer.parseInt(amount)>100000){
                        returnparam= "<html><body><h3>Transaction amount has exceeded the limit. Transaciton cancelled</h3></body></html>";
                    } else {
                        returnparam = "<html><body><h3>Transaciton successfull</h3></body></html>";
                    }

                } else {
                    returnparam = "<html><body><h3>Invalid card details. Transaction cancelled</h3></body></html>";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        return returnparam;

    }
}
```

Your SQL-Query will always return 1 as an output. When you are accessing the columns it will not able to find out those columns of Table. So, either you have to use `SELECT *` or specify the column names which you need.

Your `rs` variable contain a ROW, which has a Record, with column Name `1` because you are fetching result as **SELECT 1 FROM credit_card....** so it will return Record as like `ColumnName = 1` and `RecordValue = 1`

So try to change your Query, and re-run your code.

Comment: using 'select  * ' instead of 'select 1' wont solve the problem. because i am just checking whether a record exists for the given constraints. i am not retrieving the columns. so this does not solve my problem. thanks anyway